# Как адаптивно разместить ряд блоков по центру родителя?

Tags: css3, html5, центрирование

Не могу разместить блоки по центру тега `nav`

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

figure {
  background: #5f6a72;
  /* Цвет фона */
  padding: 1%;
  /* Поля вокруг */
  display: inline-block;
  /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
  width: 150px;
  /* Ширина */
  height: 250px;
  /* Ширина */
  float: left;
  /* Блоки выстраиваются по горизонтали */
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  /* Отступы */
  text-align: center;
  /* Выравнивание по центру */
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  /* Цвет текста */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .choice:nth-of-type(2n + 2) figure {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня'></p>
      <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
      <br />
      <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам
        <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Однокомнатные,<br /> двухкомнатные,<br /> 3ккв и более</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='1ккв, 2ккв, 2ккв'></p>
      <figcaption>База квартир
        <br />по количеству
        <br />комнат</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
      <figcaption>
        <br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Я, к сожалению, в CSS не сильна. Буду очень признательна за помощь.

Comment: Вопрос - а где собственно блок родителя? Его стили влияют на то, каким образом можно управлять блоком nav.

Comment: Я пока пытаюсь отдельным файлом отработать нужные стили. Родитель в данном случае body. Кстати, при уменьшении размеров экрана блоки смещаются неравномерно - 2 и 4 имеют отступы слева, которые тоже нужно "победить" :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте немного сократим ваш код, и используем `flex`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.choice {
  display: flex;
    background: #5f6a72;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <nav class='wrapper'>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня'></p>
      <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic1.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'></p>
      <br />
      <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам
        <br />и станциям метро</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Однокомнатные,<br /> двухкомнатные,<br /> 3ккв и более</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='1ккв, 2ккв, 2ккв'></p>
      <figcaption>База квартир
        <br />по количеству
        <br />комнат</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <figure>
      <h1><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h1>
      <p><img src='pic2.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'></p>
      <figcaption>
        <br />Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: О! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Пора и мне про flex взяться :)

Comment: Давно пора:) и отказаться от `<figure>` и прочего:) Обращайтесь.

Comment: @Наталья я правильно понимаю, что вас устраивает что в фулл экране все 4 блока в строку - не друг под другом по 2 , так? Но с флексом решение получилось красивым и простым)

Comment: Там задача была в другом совершенно, оцентрировать блоки в `nav`. Скажет как надо по другому, сделаем по другому.

Comment: alexoander, да на десктопах все блоки идут в строку (inline-block).

Comment: Zicrael, а чем плох тег <figure>? Я больше на SEO специализируюсь, чем на верстке. С точки зрения seo этот тег очень хорош

Comment: Уже много альтернатив есть, и на том же флексе это легче и адаптивней сделать.

Comment: ОК. Чуть посвободней буду, попробую с флексбокс поработать